# Copy text from a locked Google doc

Tags: google-docs, copy-paste

I lock my Google Docs so colleagues can't edit them, but they do need to copy and paste from them.  I have no trouble doing this from my own locked files, so why can't some of my colleagues do this, when others can?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications](/tour "Web Apps Tour"). Consider [registering your account](/users/login "Login") to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. [Registering](/users/login "Login") is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/)

Comment: @simon-moore without more details, your question is likely to be closed. Please take a moment to [edit] it to advise how you locked it (Google Drive?) and what permissions are on the document itself (Google Docs). You seem to be describing a Google Workspace document and you might try your organization's IT support as administrative permissions or another issue we can't know may also be in play,